# Unity sprite flip goes out of camera bounds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm trying to flip a sprite when arrow keys pressed but they somehow goes out of the boudnds of the camera. It seems to me the whole camera is flipped instead of the sprite. What is the right way to approach this.

I'm trying to flip when user press the left / right arrow key. Below is my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float input;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator anim;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update () 
    {
        if (input != 0) {
            print("is running");
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        } else {
            print("is not running");
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }

    if (input > 0) {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        }else if (input < 0){
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,180,0);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        input = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(input * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

this is the screenshot from the scene / game
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the scale instead of rotation.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float input;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (input != 0)
        {
            print("is running");
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }
        else
        {
            print("is not running");
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
        if (input > 0)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        }
        else if (input < 0)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        input = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(input * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```